# Why is <p> and <h1> height larger than it's contents?

Tags: css

I have a quick question, why is that my h1 and p height is bigger than it is supposed to be? Here is what I am talking about:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I have been at this for quite some time and would really appreciate some help! :) What I am trying to do is to make sure that the yellow background takes up only the amount of height and width as it needs for the text.

HTML

```
<div class="main-content">
            <div class="main-box">
              <div class="kills-container">
                <h1>5600</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="label-container">
                <p>Kills</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

CSS

```
.main-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 18.3%;
  width: 80.4%;
  height: 78%;
}

.main-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  height: 120px;
  width: 23%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  background-color: green;
}

.kills-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: red;
}

.kills-container h1 {
  margin-left: 10%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.label-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.label-container p {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Both p and h* tags have default top and bottom margins.

Comment: @jmoerdyk Why is that?

Comment: Because the browser makers define them that way in their default style sheets.

Comment: @jmoerdyk Oh. But at the start I put body{margin:0; padding:0;} shouldn't this fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put body{margin:0px; padding:0px} That only effects the body tags I believe. In order to adjust them for each other tag you would do:

```
h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
p {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Oh okay. Would it be more efficient if I did *{margin:0; padding:0;}? Thanks!: )

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. You can run into issues having to declare every margin for everything you create. Sometimes it's okay to leave them as default. Only style as needed on the fly.

Comment: Oh okay, Makes sense. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend nesting `<span>` tags inside of your `<h1>` (and/or `<p>`) tags, then applying the `line-height` and `padding` CSS properties to those elements, respectively. There's a great [article on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/your-brain-on-front-end-development/) that covers this technique for a similar use case involving multi-line text, and there's even a link to a working Codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/ZRpZLx?editors=1100).

Using spans allows you to keep the free element spacing provided by the browser (the default padding/margin) without having it interfere with text styling. If you want to do away with those defaults altogether, consider looking into a [CSS Reset](https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/).

Comment: Thanks! :) This is also a great idea!